# Collecting data for Citations network analysis

Tags: social-networking

my question is related to social network analysis. I am starting my research work on the citations network analysis of 3 universities. my question is that how   can i easily collect data for my citation network? or Is there any intelligent software which can identify references link of citations automatically? Or can I do it through simple programming?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:
http://www.vosviewer.com/Home

But I guess if you want to write your own custom-made software, it would work better, because you'd be able to fine-tune it exactly for your needs.

Which package to recommend depends on the languages you know. I think most of the existing modules for this sort of stuff are written in Python, so if you're familiar with it, go ahead and google some citation extractors.

Alternatively, you could program it yourself, shouldn't be that hard. Consider using a graph database, like Neo4J for it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that you asked this question on the day Nature published the [Leiden Manifesto](http://www.leidenmanifesto.org/)

@Dmitry Paranyushkin turned me to VOSViewer

Watch this video and learn how to collect/import data into VOSviewer

Your institution will have to has access to [Web of Science](http://www.isiknowledge.com) to collect the publication data.

For you specific purpose you may find [CitNetExplorer](http://www.citnetexplorer.nl/) more useful.

Also, check out the parent organization [Centre for Science and Technology Studies](https://www.cwts.nl/) at Leiden University.